# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Не понимаю, почему возникает эта ошибка. Ниже код:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as LDA
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis as QDA
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC

def create_lagged_series(symbol, start_date, end_date, lags=5):

    ts = pdr(symbol, "google",
            start_date-datetime.timedelta(days=365),
            end_date)

    # Create the new lagged DataFrame
    tslag = pd.DataFrame(index=ts.index)
    tslag["Today"] = ts["Adj Close"]
    tslag["Volume"] = ts["Volume"]

    # Create the shifted lag series of prior trading period close values
    for i in range(0, lags):
        tslag["Lag%s" % str(i+1)] = ts["Adj Close"].shift(i+1)

    # Create the returns DataFrame
    tsret = pd.DataFrame(index=tslag.index)
    tsret["Volume"] = tslag["Volume"]
    tsret["Today"] = tslag["Today"].pct_change()*100.0

    # If any of the values of percentage returns equal zero, set them to
    # a small number (stops issues with QDA model in scikit-learn)
    for i,x in enumerate(tsret["Today"]):
        if (abs(x) < 0.0001):
            tsret["Today"][i] = 0.0001

    # Create the lagged percentage returns columns
    for i in range(0, lags):
        tsret["Lag%s" % str(i+1)] = \
        tslag["Lag%s" % str(i+1)].pct_change()*100.0

    # Create the "Direction" column (+1 or -1) indicating an up/down day
    tsret["Direction"] = np.sign(tsret["Today"])
    tsret = tsret[tsret.index >= start_date]

    return tsret
```

При выполнении, например:

```
snpret = create_lagged_series("^GSPC", datetime.datetime(2001,1,10), datetime.datetime(2013,12,31), lags=10)
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-271a01a939b3> in <module>()
----> 1 snpret = create_lagged_series("^GSPC",     datetime.datetime(2001,1,10), datetime.datetime(2013,12,31), lags=10)

<ipython-input-2-d16e6c560a08> in create_lagged_series(symbol,  start_date, end_date, lags)
     12     ts = pdr(symbol, "google",
     13             start_date-datetime.timedelta(days=365),
---> 14             end_date)
     15 
     16     # Create the new lagged DataFrame

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Ну да, модуль вызывать и правда нельзя. Что вы ожидали получить, пытаясь вызвать pandas_datareader?

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!

Comment: @Andrey, попробуйте так: `from pandas_datareader import data as web; ts = web.DataReader(...)` Но в последнее время и `yahoo` и `google` заблокировали данные бесплатные сервисы :(

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! Про блокировку "yahoo" и "google" я уже тоже понял. Осталось разобраться как же все-таки эти данные получить :-)

Comment: @Andrey, дайте знать если сумеете обойти :)